# Intel drivers, shader model 3.0

Tags: opengl, intel, drivers

I  downloaded the drivers for Intel(R) HD Graphics version 8.15.10.2993 which are known to support shader 3.0. but after installation I have checked it by Geeks 3d caps viewer and calling `gl.glGetString(GL2.GL_VERSION)`  code and showed just 2.1.0.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GL 2.1.0 / GLSL 1.20 is fine for shader model 3. GL 3.x/GLSL >=1.30 requires shader model 4.

Comment: anyway it doesn't support GL3 context GL3 gl3 = glad.getGL().getGL3();, after running shows error "Not a GL3 implementation", though, shader model 3 is supported.

Comment: @Vitrum: that;s exactly what I said. "Shader model numbers" are not synchronised witth GL versions in any way. Your GL implementation does not support GL3. Ans shader model 3.0 is not enought for GL3.